# Muliticolumn in clause in query dsl

Tags: querydsl

I am new to query dsl and i have a requirement to fetch the records from a table based on two columns
I have a table called Employee and want to fetch the records bases on firstname and lastname.
If i want all the list of records with firstname then i can use in query with that column.
If i want bulk select with first name and last name then i use some query like the following
SELECT *
FROM Employee tabb
WHERE (tabb.firstname, tabb.lastname) IN ( (a,b), (a,c),(e,d))

I want to convert the above query in query dsl...?and run it to get the result.
I am not seeing a way to do this in query dsl...
Is there a way to do this...

Thanks,
Swati

Answer (score 0):

Querydsl doesn't support multicolumn in expressions, so you will need to express this via chaining or expressions

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
for (...) {
    builder.or(prop1.eq(a).and(prop2.eq(b));
}
query.where(builder);
```